# How to trigger an Azure DevOps pipeline on a specific folder in any workspace in a repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that I want to run on any changes to files in `src/*/foo/bar` in my repository.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
  paths:
    include:
      - src/*/foo/bar
```

Unfortunately, the `*` does not work for this purpose.  It will work if I hardcode the path (like `src/workspace/foo/bar`).

How can I get it to run the way I want?  Should I use `*/foo/bar`?

Comment: Should be supported. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-192-update?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#support-for-wild-cards-in-path-filters Are you on Azure DevOps Server by any chance?

Comment: Maybe that update hasn't carried over to my company, but the wildcard just doesn't work.  I do not believe we use Azure DevOps Server.

Comment: Have you checked if it works if you use globstar style i.e. with two asterisks: `src/**/foo/bar` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the only problem was a missing "/" at the beginning of the trigger path. It's working now automatically with that added (and using "**" for the recursive search).

Answer (score 1):

The path spec does allow wildcards, see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32281544)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, [azure devops paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths) specification does not include wildcard support.

One trick you could do is to have a pipeline that triggers on `src/`, and have that pipeline trigger another pipeline if the changes are in the specific paths you're interested in. You'll have to keep track of the last commit that you looked at, so you can do it incrementally on each run. This is heavy weight, and not trivial. I don't know of any other way though.